# First x frames from a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I need to get the first x frames from a video (usually FLV) and turn it into a GIF. The idea is to use these GIFs as a short preview for the real thing.

At the moment, we're using ffmpeg and imagemagick to do that:

```
ffmpeg -y -i movie.flv -pix_fmt rgb32 -r fps extracted/%d.png

convert extracted/0.png ... extracted/50.png -delay 4 -loop 0 \
-set dispose Background -sample 256x256> preview.gif
```

So basically, first the frames are extracted, converted to PNG, then the PNGs are put together again into a GIF. There are a lot of unnecessary steps involved here.

Does anyone have any suggestions for speeding up this process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I right in thinking you are creating animated gifs? Have you tried creating an animated gif directly from ffmpeg. I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

*FFMPEG* is not very good at creating animated gifs. They will be uncompressed, according to [the docs](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Image-Formats). But ffmpeg is very versatile when it comes to reading different video codecs.

*ImageMagick* can create good animated gifs, but only has very limited video capabilities. However, it [apparently has rudimentary .avi support.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/)

You could do without the intermediary png files by converting the input video to a generic avi stream with `ffmpeg` and directly piping this into `convert`.

This works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -t 1 -f avi -|convert -delay 1 - preview.gif
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but I actually got an error, namely:

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-vzjPD8ux' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: no images defined `preview.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.

I have DELEGATES mpeg png x11 zlib in identify -list configure. Any idea how I can make IM accept the avi?